# pattern matching and selecting digits for printing

Tags: awk, gawk

I have a file with a long line containing many columns with header for each column something like this.

```
BMR_22@O15-BMR_1@O23-H23 BMR_14@O22-BMR_1@O26-H26 BMR_14@O14-BMR_1@O26-H26 BMR_14@O12-BMR_1@O16-H16 BMR_17@O26-BMR_2@O24-H24 BMS_88@O22-BMR_4@O22-H22 BMS_89@O22-BMR_4@O26-H26 BMS_89@O12-BMR_4@O12-H12 BMR_15@O25-BMR_15@O26-H26 BMS_96@O25-BMR_5@O16-H16 BMR_13@O23-BMR_6@O26-H26 BMR_27@O22-BMR_126@O12-H12 BMR_17@O26-BMR_6@O13-H13 BMR_26@O26-BMR_6@O16-H16 BMR_29@O26-BMR_7@O16-H16 BMS_86@O23-BMR_19@O26-H26 BMS_78@O16-BMR_9@O16-H16 BMS_96@O24-BMR_10@O23-H23 BMR_14@O25-BMR_11@O24-H24 BMS_90@O22-BMR_11@O26-H26 BMR_25@O13-BMR_11@O12-H12 BMR_120@O24-BMR_11@O13-H13 BMR_25@O22-BMR_11@O13-H13 BMS_65@O24-BMR_12@O23-H23 BMR_31@O11-BMR_12@O12-H12
```

I would like to select columns based on some criteria.
If use command as below:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^BMR_[1-9]@O13-BMR/) print $i } ' inPutFile
```

I get something like:

```
BMR_1@O13-BMR_14@O13-H13
BMR_2@O13-BMR_16@O13-H13
BMR_6@O13-BMR_27@O23-H23
BMR_2@O13-BMR_16@O12-H12
BMR_1@O13-BMR_30@O26-H26
BMR_1@O13-BMR_11@O23-H23
BMR_1@O13-BMR_14@O22-H22
BMR_6@O13-BMR_27@O22-H22
```

If I use command as below:

```
awk 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^BMR_[1-9][1-9]@O13-BMR/) print $i } ' inPutFile
```

I get output as below:

```
BMR_25@O13-BMR_11@O12-H12
BMR_26@O13-BMR_25@O12-H12
BMR_17@O13-BMR_27@O13-H13
BMR_64@O13-BMR_39@O12-H12
BMR_58@O13-BMR_44@O16-H16
BMR_36@O13-BMR_61@O12-H12
BMR_36@O13-BMR_61@O13-H13
```

What could be the command if I want to select both, single and double digits (like **BMR_2**@O13-BMR_16@O12-H12 and **BMR_26**@O13-BMR_25@O12-H12) in one run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the repetition as 1 or 2 in single awk command like below:

```
awk --posix 'NR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~/^BMR_[1-9]{1,2}@O13-BMR/) print $i } ' inPutFile
```

Comment: Why do you add `--posix`?  If you need this to work `{1,2}` then use `--re-interval`.  The posix option removes all `gnu` function from `gnu awk`  Newer  `gnu awk` like >4.0 does not need this any longer.  Same with older.  So you should mention that if line does not work with your `gnu awk`, add `--re-interval`